# TranslateAnimation moves the view, but without animation

Tags: android, android-layout, translate-animation, android-windowmanager

I am developing a floatie, similar to the chatHead in facebook or the floatie in OneNote.

Once I have created it, I need to be able to move it by touching the icon, but when I stop dragging, and release the finger, I want the icon to return to the left edge of the screen.

By using TranslateAnimation it works, but without animation. Icon appears at the left edge when I touch again on the icon.

This is the relevant code:

```
    trackerHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private int initialX;
        private int initialY;
        private float initialTouchX;
        private float initialTouchY;

        @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = params.x;
                    initialY = params.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
                            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, params.x,
                            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, initialX,
                            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, params.y,
                            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, params.y);
                    animation.setDuration(4000);
                    animation.setRepeatCount(1);
                    animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                    trackerHead.startAnimation(animation);
                    params.x = initialX;
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(trackerHead, params);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

where trackerHead is an ImageView that is added to the screen by mean of WindowManager.

When MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is received, I want the icon to return to the left edge of the screen smoothly.

Visually, when I drag the icon, and then release the finger, the icon remains at the same position. When I touch again on it, the icon appears fast at the left edge, which is obvious cause of "params.x = initialX;" instruction.

Any help, please?
Thanks
Jaime

Comment: I also have a solution with Animators instead of the MoveAnimator if you want.

Answer (score 5):

I implemented a similar feature.
I took some inspiration from [bubbles for Android](https://github.com/txusballesteros/bubbles-for-android) and [Magnet](https://github.com/premnirmal/Magnet), but I adjusted it to your request.

```
//your imageView
private ImageView trackerHead;
private boolean isBeingDragged;
private WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );

//Constructor or entry for your WindowManager service
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    animator = new MoveAnimator();
    this.trackerHead.setOnTouchListener(this);
    windowManager.addView(trackerHead, params);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getRaw  X();
    float y = event.getRawY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            animator.stop();
            isBeingDragged = true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            isBeingDragged = false;
            stickToLeftWall();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (isBeingDragged) {
                move(x - lastXPose, y - lastYPose);
            }
            break;
    }

    lastXPose = x;
    lastYPose = y;

    return false;
}

private void stickToLeftWall() {
    animator.start(this, 0); 
}
```

The MoveAnimator class can be placed as an inner class.

```
class MoveAnimator implements Runnable {

    private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    private float destinationX;
    private float destinationY;
    private long startingTime;

    private void start(float x, float y) {
        this.destinationX = x;
        this.destinationY = y;
        startingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        handler.post(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (trackerHead != null && trackerHead.getParent() != null) {
            float progress = Math.min(1, (System.currentTimeMillis() - startingTime) / 400f);
            float deltaX = (destinationX - mLayoutParams.x) * progress;
            float deltaY = (destinationY - mLayoutParams.y) * progress;
            move(deltaX, deltaY);
            if (progress < 1) {
                handler.post(this);
            }
        }
    }

    private void stop() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(this);
    }
}
```

The important thing here is the `stickToLeftWall` function. It will let your ImageView always return to 0 on the X-axis. However if you like you could get the `screenWidth` of your device and calculate the closest wall to which your ImageView should snap.

I suggest you take a look at the Github code provided.